# sql server desired output from tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
                                         
        ID     name       Dept       Manager       
        101    Mukesh     SW               
        102    Ram        SW         101       
        103    sham       SW         101       
        104    rahul      SW         101       
        105    Rajat      HQ               
        106    akhilesh   HQ         105         
        107    sachin     HQ         105
```

I've this table and I want output like below

```
                                  
        dep    Manager    name          
        SW     Mukesh     Ram       
                          Sham          
                          Rahul         
        HQ     Rajat      akhilesh
```

Comment: what databae are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly find below query as you want. i created MyTest as table name which you need to replace.

```
SELECT 
    Case WHEN ISNULL(SecondTable.Id,0) = 0
         THEN FirstTable.Dept
         ELSE ''
    END As Department, 

    Case WHEN ISNULL(SecondTable.Id,0) = 0
         THEN Manager.Name 
         ELSE ''
    END  As Manager, 
    FirstTable.Name FROM MyTest As FirstTable
LEFT JOIN MyTest As SecondTable ON
    SecondTable.ID = (SELECT Top 1  MyTest.ID
                      FROM MyTest 
                      WHERE MyTest.Manager = FirstTable.Manager
                        AND MyTest.dept = FirstTable.dept
                        AND MyTest.Id < FirstTable.Id
                      ORDER BY MyTest.ID Desc) 
LEFT JOIN MyTest As Manager On Manager.Id = FirstTable.Manager  WHERE FirstTable.Manager <> 0 ORDER BY FirstTable.dept, FirstTable.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is to retrieve the hierachical data, with sql 2008 you can use common table expression. check out this link [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) the data output is flat (it will repeat SW and Mukesh for each row). 
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible in sql only. What you can do is get the dep and manager name for each of them.

```
SELECT t1.Dept AS DEP, t2.name AS MANAGER, t1.name AS NAME
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.manager = t2.id
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d9da/3)</kbd>

This will return something like:

```
DEP MANAGER NAME
SW  Mukesh  Ram
SW  Mukesh  sham
SW  Mukesh  rahul
HQ  Rajat   akhilesh
HQ  Rajat   sachin
```

Then in your programming language of choice you would do that formatting.